# How to solve this question: $(5^x-5^{-x})/2=3$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

> How to solve this question? $(5^x-5^{-x})/2=3$. Express your answer to the nearest hundredth.

Cannot figure this one out. I get stuck at $\log (5^x-5^{-x})=\log 6$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y=5^x $ and then solve an equation in $y. $ you should get a quadratic in $y$ ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

Sinh(x.ln5)=3 => x=argsh(3)/ln(5)